# Scrolling navbar (navbar-fixed) only on Desktop

Tags: css, materialize

I want to make a navbar that scrolls with the site.
Now, if I just wanted that, I'd just add `.navbar-fixed` and call it a day.
However, I want that only on desktop.
On mobile, I want it to stay at the top.

Is there a way I can do that?
I've looked into jQuery for this, but everybody says I should use media queries for this (to which I do agree).

The code for my navbar is very simple with no additional CSS.:

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <nav> 
        <div class="nav-wrapper container"> 
            <a href="#" class="brand-img img-responsive" wp-home-url wp-home-url-set="href" wp-home-url-scheme="relative">
                <img src="https://www.finlaydag33k.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo-FDG-300-01-300x300.png">
            </a>             
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right"> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-activates="side-nav-150" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                </li>                 
            </ul>             
        </div>         
    </nav>
</div>
```

so tl;dr:
On desktop: make it like it's having `.navbar-fixed`.
On phone: make like it doesn't have `.navbar-fixed`.

Comment: share your code either here or on fiddle

Comment: updated the OP.

Comment: gave you a few solutions in my answer below. Let me know if they work for you ( they should :)  )

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions for this .

**1.** Using **CSS** media queries .

***1.a.*** First make your navbar fixed using `position:fixed` , and then under
    `767px` ( which is mobile ) change it to `position:relative` or
    `absolute` depending on what you want.

See snippet below or > [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37402/)

```css
.content {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
.navbar {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position:relative;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <nav> 
        <div class="nav-wrapper container"> 
            <a href="#" class="brand-img img-responsive" wp-home-url wp-home-url-set="href" wp-home-url-scheme="relative">
                <img src="https://www.finlaydag33k.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo-FDG-300-01-300x300.png">
            </a>             
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right"> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-activates="side-nav-150" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                </li>                 
            </ul>             
        </div>         
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

***1.b.*** You can also make a media query for desktop only.

See snippet below or > [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37401/)

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-img img-responsive" wp-home-url wp-home-url-set="href" wp-home-url-scheme="relative">
        <img src="https://www.finlaydag33k.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo-FDG-300-01-300x300.png">
      </a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-activates="side-nav-150" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

**2.** Use **jQuery** for this and add class `navbar-fixed` in html and remove it when on mobile. See below or > [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37400/)

```js
var wWidth = $(window).width()

if ( wWidth < 767) {
    $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top")
}
```

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-img img-responsive" wp-home-url wp-home-url-set="href" wp-home-url-scheme="relative">
        <img src="https://www.finlaydag33k.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo-FDG-300-01-300x300.png">
      </a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-activates="side-nav-150" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: the jQuery solution does work, but I wanted to refrain from using them as people keep telling me it might give bugs down the road.

However, I managed to use your stuff as inspiration for the solution that I'll post in a moment :)

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs all of them should work. what was the problem ?

Comment: I don't know, what theproblem was.
Either it went all fixed, or none was fixed.
with a dash of conent in front of the navbar added here and there :\

Answer (score 0):

using `@Mihai T`'s (I don't know how to tag people here on SO) post as inspiration and a bit of a guide, I managed to get a working solution:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
    .navbar-fixed nav
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-fixed
    {
        position: relative;
        height: 56px;
        z-index: 998;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: doesn't this make the `.navbar-fixed` be `fixed` on mobile ? i don't understand this solution

Comment: I don't exactly understand why this solution works either.
But it works, and looks neat I guess